# jqgrid search without operators

Tags: css, jqgrid

Is it possible to implement jqGrid search without operators? I need the operator to default to 'contains'. I don't want to modify the original jqgrid js or css files because they will be overwritten when we upgrade to a new version.

I need the dialog to look like this:

[image]

I can override displaying the operators dropdown by defining:

```
.operators
{
    display: none;
}
```

I need to also adjust the width.

Comment: You could use jQuery to add a search function to the div without modifying the div itself.

Comment: Isn't better to use [the searching toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) instead?

Comment: @Oleg good suggestion...it would make more sense.

Comment: @Oleg Except I only want to enable searching on one field at a time. Having a look at your sample project with advanced toolbar searching now in any case...looks really cool :)

Comment: I use mostly combination of toolbar searching and advanced searching with `multipleSearch: true` and `multipleGroup: true` (or single field searching). The users find toolbar searching very intuitive. The usage of dialogs could be practical to create more complex queries. One can create searching templates additionally. By the way, it's important to define `sopt` on some fields. The toolbar searching use `defaultSearch` if no `sopt` are defined and use *first* operation from `searchoptions.sopt` array if `sopt` are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this seems to work although it will change the default width for all jqgrid dialogs:

```
.operators
{
    display: none;
}

.ui-jqdialog
{
    width:220px !important;
}
```